# Matlab - data structure object - variance-covariance

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have a **data structure object** containing Index prices data. In the structure there are n sub-arrays each representing a security and containing dates and prices. 
 
 What is the best way to create a **variance-covariance matrix**(based on log returns) for the index constituents

```
Index:
-Security1 [Date,ClosePrice]
-Security2 [Date,ClosePrice]
..
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Matlab.  Also, questions about mathematical techniques are better suited for math.stackechange.com, or possibly for the finance stack exchange site.  On stack overflow, the format is to post code that you've tried to write and then ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several comments:

1. You can't create an accurate return series using only price data because you are missing dividends and distributions.
2. If you assume no dividends and no distributions, the return series would be: `R = P ./ lagmatrix(P, 1)` (assuming the price array `P` is in a strict order of increasing date)
3. Log returns would be `r = log(R)` (and we can trivially see would be difference in log price).
4. Once you have a series, you can use `cov` or `var` functions..